# Mapping Vault CLI Path to Packer Vault Path

Tags: path, hashicorp-vault, packer

Using the Vault CLI I am able to get data for the following path:

```sh
vault kv get -field=databag chef0/databags/wireguard/hedge
```

However, in my Packer script, this:

```sh
 "{{ vault `chef0/databags/wireguard/hedge` `databag` }}"
```

generates a no data error:

```sh
template: root:1:3: executing "root" at <vault `chef0/databags/wireguard/hedge`
`databag`>: error calling vault: Vault data was empty at the given path.
Warnings: Invalid path for a versioned K/V secrets engine. See the API docs for
the appropriate API endpoints to use. If using the Vault CLI, use 'vault kv get'
for this operation.
```

Is there a rule for translating/mapping one to the other?

Note:
To eliminate unrelated permission issues I have run both these using a root token.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, not sure where this is documented, and am not suggesting it isn't, but here is what I discovered:

It appears any data stored in a secret, say chef0, is accessible via the API under a `data` sub-path.  It may also help you to know there is a `metadata` sub-path- at the same level as `data`.

So it appears the Vault CLI does not expose these sub-paths, by the Vault HTTP-API and the Packer Vault-API expose these sub-paths.

The correct Packer incantation (chickens optional) is:

```sh
 "{{ vault `chef0/**data**/databags/wireguard/hedge` `databag` }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be using v2 of the kv engine. For that engine, you do indeed need to have `/data/` in the path, as shown in the [API docs](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/secret/kv/kv-v2). The requirement for this prefix is also described in [the engine docs](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/kv/kv-v2#acl-rules). I've certainly run into this same problem myself :-)